Cannot resolve method 'autowire'
I have the following code which I want to migrate to Spring Boot 3.x.x:
@Configuration
public class MessageConfiguration {

  @Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
  @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
  MessageConsumer getMessageConsumer() {
    return new KafkaMessageConsumer();
  }
}

I get error: Cannot resolve method 'autowire'
I tried to remove autowire like this @Bean(Autowire.BY_TYPE) but I get:
Incompatible types. Found: 'org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire', required: 'java.lang.String[]'
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowire.java
Do you know how I can migrate the code properly?

The error tells you exactly what is wrong. You are using an enum where you should use a String. Inyour case, check the javadoc which String to use, it is the actual value wrapped in the enum. The one from the AutowireCapableBeanFactory that is.

Unfortunately I can't find a solution.

My bad, the autowire argument has been deprecated since Spring 5.0 and has been removed in 6.0. Remove it. What you did was already the default (BY_TYPE) in this case remove it.

hm... you mean to remove @Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE) and just leave @Bean

Yes exactly that.

The @Bean autowire attribute became deprecated in version 5.1 due to the advancement of @Bean factory method argument resolution and @Autowired processing, which outperformed the traditional name/type-based bean property injection. In Spring 6.x, this attribute has been entirely eliminated.
So no syntactical alternative,Just change   @Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE) to @Bean
.

The @Bean notation is in Spring Boot 3.x.x not longer supported für autowire attributes.
You can try using constructor injection.
You can edit your code to something like this:
@Bean
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
MessageConsumer getMessageConsumer(KafkaMessageConsumer KafkaMessageConsumer) {
    return KafkaMessageConsumer;
  }

